# Report with WPF and EF in VS 2010

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, crystal-reports

I need to quickly build a report. In VS 2010 when I'm adding new item in the 'Reporting' brach there are 3 items:

- Report Wizard;
- Report;

and

- Crystal Report

I tried to play with the first one - couldn't find a way to get the data through existing entity model. Also I stupidly confused what's the real difference between 'Report' and 'crystal Report'?

Could you guys point me out at some walkthrough tutorial or something about how to build a simple report using these things?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Microsoft link regarding the wizard:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb558709.aspx

One is a Reporting Services report and the other is Crystal Reports. Two *completely* different models.